# Optimize coordinate calculations in two nested arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, google-maps

I'm working on an application in which there is an array of coordinates on the `Google` map by which the route is drawn. There is a second array of filling stations coordinates. In two arrays of 10,000 points.  I need to show the points from the second array that fall on the route with a deviation of 5 miles. I made this requirement in nested arrays, but this calculation is very lengthy, it takes about five minutes. How can it be optimized and speed up the calculation? I will be very grateful for any advice:

**Here is my code**

```
- (void)addRandomPointsOnMap {
CGFloat upperBoundLatitude = 46.80;
CGFloat lowerBoundLatitude = 29.76;
CGFloat upperBoundLongitude = -118.64;
CGFloat lowerBoundLongitude = -75.6;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    TSPoint *randomPoint = [[TSPoint alloc] init];
    randomPoint.latitude = [self randomFloatBetween:upperBoundLatitude
                                          and:lowerBoundLatitude];
    randomPoint.longitude = [self randomFloatBetween:upperBoundLongitude
                                           and:lowerBoundLongitude];
    CLLocation *randomPointLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:randomPoint.latitude longitude:randomPoint.longitude];

    for (int i = 0; i < _routePoints.count; i++) {
        TSPoint *routePoint = _routePoints[i];
        CLLocation *routePointLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:routePoint.latitude longitude:routePoint.longitude];
        NSInteger distanceInMeters = [routePointLocation distanceFromLocation:randomPointLocation];

        NSInteger distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters / 1609.344;
        if (distanceInMiles < 5) {

            GMSMarker *markerT1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
            markerT1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(randomPoint.latitude, randomPoint.longitude);
            markerT1.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_pin"];
            markerT1.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
            markerT1.map = _mapView;
        }
    }
} }
```

and the method of calculating random coordinates in bounded ranges:

```
- (float)randomFloatBetween:(float)lowerBound and:(float)upperBound {
float diff = upperBound - lowerBound;
return (((float) (arc4random() % ((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1)) / RAND_MAX) * diff) + lowerBound; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of points that determine the route. My assumption is that there are very many points that are located at insignificant distances one from another, given the 5 miles deviation.

Here's an example:
The first point in your route is at a given location. The second point in your route is 3 feet away from the previous location. Considering that you have found a filling station that falls within 5 miles of the first location, it is safe to presume that it will also fall within 5 miles of the second location. Therefore, all stations that have already been verified for the first location no longer need to be checked for the second location.

I think you see where I am trying to go with this. Try to reduce the points in your route with a distance that works for you.

You can start with 1/20 of your deviation. That means that every location on route that is within 0.25 miles from another location that has already had the stations verified will no longer verify for stations, since it will assume there will be the same stations as for the verified one.

Here's how reducing would be:

```
- (NSArray *)reducePointsInArray:(NSArray*)locations withinDistance:(CGFloat)distance {
     NSMutableArray *mutableLocations = [locations mutableCopy];

     //This array will hold the indexes of insignificant locations
     NSMutableArray *reduceIndexes = [NSMutableArray array];

     //Start with a reference location
     CLLocation referenceLocation = [locations firstObject];
     [locations enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CLLocation *location, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
         //Don't compare first location to first location
         if (idx == 0) {
             return;
         }
         //Compare location with reference location
         if([locations distanceFromLocation:referenceLocation] < distance) {
             [reduceIndexes addObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:idx]];
         } else {
             referenceLocation = location;
         }
    }];
    [mutableLocations removeObjectsAtIndexes:reduceIndexes];
    return mutableLocations;
}
```

If you consider that 0.25 miles is too much for reducing the route locations, you can go with less, I think it will still reduce some of the locations. Try with different values and log the number of locations before and after reducing. Depending on the distances between your route points, I guess you could even reduce up to 80% of them without significantly affecting your results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I know that the distance between the points of the route is very small and I now understand what you mean in order to decrease the iterations. That is, if a filling station is found within a radius of 5 miles, then the next check of the coordinates should be done with the value of the deviation radius, that is, minus five miles?

Comment: No, what I mean is, you take the first location and get the station for it. Then consider that all found stations also apply to the next locations that are within 0.25 miles from the first location. The 0.25 miles location is the distance in the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for pushing the idea. I understood how to decide on

Comment: I appreciated the answer, but I have a low rating and my assessment is not visible